# Video background and text inside of div does not scroll with rest of the page?

Tags: html, css, video, background

I'm trying to make a video background with text over it positioned in a certain way but when I scroll the whole page up the text and video do not scroll/move? What am I doing wrong?

````
  position: fixed;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  min-width:100%;
  min-height:100%;
  color: #fff;
  z-index:0;
  text-shadow: 0 0 5px #000000;
}

 .overlayText {
position: fixed;
top: 25%;
left: 25%;
color:#fff;
z-index:1;
}

<div class="bannervideo">
  <video autoplay loop muted class="bannervideo" poster="video.jpg">
    <source src="/s/Blueheadervideos.mp4" type="video/mp4">
  </video>
  <center><div class="overlayText">
    <p style="font-size:3vw; font-weight: 500;">Headline here</p>
    <p style="font-size:1.5vw; font-weight: 500;">tagline</p> </div>

     <div class="overlaybottomText">
<p style="font-size:1.5vw;">More words go here </p> 
  </div>  ```
````

Answer (score 1):

The `position: fixed;` on both selectors will fix elements relative to the window. Try `position: absolute` instead for `.overlayText`

```
.overlayText {
    position: absolute;
    top: 25%;
    left: 25%;
    color:#fff;
    z-index:1;
}
```

and `position: absolute` or `position: relative` for the parent element `.bannervideo`.

Comment: Yes, when I put absolute as position then it will scroll, but I cannot get the same layout to work.. the video has white on the sides and then the words are pushed all the way to the right side?

Comment: Could you please provide your HTML to debug this issue?